# Returning a declared array in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm currently stuck on a problem with a stored procedure. I have to return an array / list of calculated data from that stored procedure.

Retrieving it with a server using Entity Framework but the problem isn't here.

I want to return data that are like this:

```
field1 : int,
field2 : string,
field3 : int,
calculatedData : List<int>
```

At the moment my procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GDF_UNITE_Previsionnel]
AS
    DECLARE @calculatedData TABLE(jour int, valeur int)

    SELECT
        field1,
        field2 , 
        field3
    FROM
        (... content )
    ...
```

I would like to return the `calculatedData` but I don't have any idea how to do it.

Maybe by changing my procedure structure ?

Hope someone could help me to do it.

Tried to include the array in my select but doesn't work. Didn't find any information on how to do it on internet. The SELECT ... FROM has to be here in the procedure.

Comment: Sql server does not have arrays, it has tables. Also the return from a stored procedure is an int. To return values from a procedure you can use select statements which will return result sets. You can also use OUTPUT parameters. But from what you posted I have no idea what you are trying to do here.

Comment: The format of the expected output is almost a JSON, so `SELECT ... FROM ... FOR JSON AUTO` is a possible option.

Comment: `Data` is one of those words in English that doesn't really have a plural - it's singular and plural at the same time - so there's no "datas" in English, really ....

Comment: @SeanLange I will call this procedure with a server using EntityFramework. So I'm not sure I could use the output parameters in this case

Comment: @marc_s Noticed for the next time, I won't do the mistake :D

Answer (score -1):

method 1

return an json structure from your select statement.   The nest json will act like an array in your json data.  Based on your example, the json subquery can have one or more records.

Now you can convert the json data to a diction in python and retrieve the values recursively

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
select 
      Field1
      ,Field2
      ,Field3
      ,(select * from dbo.myTable myTable2 
            where myTable2.Field1=myTable.Field1
            for json path) as data
  FROM dbo.myTable myTable
  where myTable.Field1=123
  for json path
```

method 2

try creating a temp table instead of an array then insert values into the temp table.

```
declare @tmp_table as table(newid uniqueidentifier , field1 varchar(10));

insert into @tmp_table(newid,field1) values(newid(),'a'),(newid(),'b')
select * from @tmp_table
```

you can now use the newid as a hashkey for updating the table similar to a dictionary which simulates an array.